# How to create an Observable Collection of other Obversable Collections? MVVM Pattern

Tags: c#, wpf, windows-phone-7, design-patterns, mvvm

I'm learning about the development in the MVVM pattern and came across the following question.

Assuming I have some observable collections, I need to create another who manage these "daughters", as would be the case?

Below is the model of one of my collections, I have 3 following the same pattern as this but for other objects.

```
public class AppointmentAndExamViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
    {
         private ObservableCollection<AppointmentAndExam> _itemsAppointmentAndExam;

         public AppointmentAndExamViewModel()
         {
             this.ItemsAppointmentAndExam = new ObservableCollection<AppointmentAndExam>();
         }

         public ObservableCollection<AppointmentAndExam> ItemsAppointmentAndExam
         {
             get { return this._itemsAppointmentAndExam; }
             set
             {
                 this._itemsAppointmentAndExam = value;
                 OnPropertyChanged("ItemsAppointmentAndExam");
             }
         }

         public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
         private void OnPropertyChanged(string name)
         {
             PropertyChangedEventHandler handler = this.PropertyChanged;
             if (handler != null)
                 handler(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(name));
         }
    }
```

Comment: Not directly answering your question, but usually when I see something like "AppointmentAndExamViewModel" (keyword being "AND") it's likely that you are violating the Single Responsibility Principle. Why are these things together? Do they need to be? Are you maybe running into a complex problem that could be avoided altogether with a cleaner design?

Comment: @MitchellLee this does not solve my problem... is a matter of choice and planning of the system was not set by me, I just need to solve my doubt.

Comment: What do you mean by another collection to manage the others? What are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: @CKII I think it would only be to facilitate access to data and maintain the MVVM pattern. Therefore it is possible to maintain a standard and the development becomes more robust and easier. Am I right?

Comment: What you have now seems fine to me. Create a class with a property for your `ObservableCollection` of models, then create an `ObservableCollection` of that class, so your end result when binding would be something like `CollectionA[x].CollectionB[y]`. Ideally you want to have syntax like `ObservableCollection<MyParentClass>`, and avoid having something like  `ObservableCollection<ObservableCollection<MyChildClass>>`

Comment: @Rachel Could you illustrate this as response code here in the topic? Thank you!

Comment: @LuizNegrini Sure, answer added :)

Comment: @LuizNegrini It may not have answered your question, which is why I listed it as a comment. If your goal is indeed to facilitate access to data and maintain the MVVM pattern, I don't see how this is the solution. The whole purpose of a pattern like MVVM is to give you a good, separation of concerns (view, model, view model). I was not saying that you violating SRP, but merely suggesting that it might be the case, and that looking at the solution from a different angle might let you fix the core problems, instead of patching the existing ones.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What you have now seems fine to me.

When you want nested `ObservableCollections`, its best to create a class with a property for your `ObservableCollection` of models, then create an `ObservableCollection` of that class, so your end result when binding would be something like `ParentCollection[x].ChildCollection[y]`.

Your end goal is to have syntax like `ObservableCollection<MyParentClass>`, and avoid having something like `ObservableCollection<ObservableCollection<MyChildClass>>`. This makes your code much easier to understand and maintain :)